# undefined behaviour[s] with interface members

Tags: vb.net, interface, directx

This is the story:

I want to make a vb.NET code from the DiretX 10 C++ code, the function `D3DX10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()` works fine with me :

```
Public Declare Function D3DX10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain Lib "d3dx10_43.dll" _
    (ByVal pAdapter As IDXGIAdapter,
     ByVal drivertype As D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE,
     ByVal software As IntPtr,
     ByVal flags As UInteger,
     ByRef pswapchaindesc As DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC,
     ByRef ppSwapChain As IntPtr,
     ByRef ppDevice As IntPtr) As Integer`
```

The rest of code is:

```
Dim swapChainDesc As New DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC()
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = Me.Width
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = Me.Height
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT.DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = 1L << (1 + 4) 
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = Me.Handle
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = True


Dim sc As IntPtr
Dim d As IntPtr
D3DX10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(Nothing,D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE.D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,IntPtr.Zero,0,swapChainDesc,sc,d)
```

and to convert intptr to a valid interface object i use (it works fine):

```
Dim s As IDXGISwapChain = CType(Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(sc, GetType(IDXGISwapChain)), IDXGISwapChain)
Dim device As ID3D10Device = CType(Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(d, GetType(ID3D10Device)), ID3D10Device)

Dim surface As ID3D10Texture2D
s.GetBuffer(0, Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(GetType(ID3D10Texture2D)), surface)
```

until here the code returns success.

```
Dim rtv As ID3D10RenderTargetView
Dim hresult As Integer = device.CreateRenderTargetView(surface, Nothing, rtv)
surface.Release() ' this works fine
MsgBox(rtv IsNot Nothing)
```

the question is :

when i change the location (the ranking of the members between them into the interface ID3D10Device), i get either AccessViolationException or 
ArgumentException for the line 
Dim hresult as ...

why this undefined behaviours?

REMARKS : the interface ID3D10Device contains more than 80 members, i have also change some members locations and they work fine.

Comment: First, don't use DirectX 10. There's literally no point. Use DirectX 11 as it supports all the same platforms, supports more hardware, and is generally better supported by tools and libraries. Second, writing your own managed assemblies to wrap DirectX is quite challenging. I recommend looking at [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). Avoid using the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/)

Comment: any idea please.